# Oracle SQL - CASE syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when, booleanquery

Assume this query which functions fine:

```
SELECT 
   first_name,
   consultant_id,
   CASE consultant_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'First Consultant'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Second Consultant'
   END
FROM consultant
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Why couldn't I add another WHEN clause using some Boolean logic other than the implied equal to in the two WHEN clauses above? For example:

```
SELECT 
   first_name,
   consultant_id,
   CASE consultant_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'First Consultant'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Second Consultant'
    WHEN BETWEEN 3 AND 12 THEN 'Everyone else'
   END
FROM consultant
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Which throws this error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 10
```

Is there a way to make this work without using the more verbose:

```
SELECT 
   first_name,
   consultant_id,
   CASE 
    WHEN consultant_id = 1 THEN 'First Consultant'
    WHEN consultant_id = 2 THEN 'Second Consultant'
    WHEN consultant_id BETWEEN 3 AND 12 THEN 'Everyone else'
   END
FROM consultant
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Comment: You now the answer.  The "more verbose" method is what you need to use.

Comment: So the WHEN clause can only handle the implied 'equal to' logic?

Comment: @ConnerM.: correct, if you need anything else you can't use the "short version"

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it is unfortunately not possible to have conditions in the short syntax.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96)
calls the short syntax "simple_case_expression"

```
CASE expr WHEN comparision_expr THEN return_expr
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, depending on your requirement, you may be able to use:

```
SELECT
   first_name,
   consultant_id,
   CASE consultant_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'First Consultant'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Second Consultant'
    ELSE 'Everyone else'
   END
FROM consultant
ORDER BY first_name
/
```